# rmarkdown, columns for text in word documents

Tags: r, ms-word, r-markdown

using Rmarkdown with R studio.
I am making a word document (html will not do).
I have a text in a rmarkdown, sometime contains code block.

I am trying to create two columns from this text. :

```
---
output: word_document
---

#Column 1
This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for 
authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R 
Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

#Column2

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that 
includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks 
within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:
```

I have been unable to find any solutions or anything close to a solution. The closes I have come is using \begin{column} and \end{column}, but it was an old tutorial and did not work for me... or I was doing it wrong.

Comment: This might help: https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/word_document_format.html#style_reference

Comment: @Benjamin this only changes styles, as I need both headers, text and a code block it will not do

Answer (score -2):

Try the following in your YAML header -

classoption: twocolumn

Comment: Please, explain more.

Comment: This option is for LaTeX output, not for Word: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/pdf-document.html#latex-options